# Something missing in configuration for publishing from VS to Docker on Ubuntu?

Tags: asp.net, ubuntu, docker

I want to publish my projects from Visual Studio to Docker service on my own server. So there are some questions rising:

1) Install Docker on Ubuntu - plenty of manuals, for example: http://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-to-docker-on-linux/
For me it ends (I think) at the point he going do "dockerize" something, but okay, at least I have the Docker installed.

2) Somehow find a way to publish VS projects to Docker. Again, plenty of manuals: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PublishingAnASPNET5AppToDockerOnLinuxWithVisualStudio.aspx

3) And the problem is when I finally choose "Publish", specifying connection and other stuff, it fails checking connection. So, Docker out of the box isn't ready to receive deployments from VS? What do I need to fill the gap?

Edit for some details:

1. Docker was installed with these exact commands with no further configuration:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 
36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc-docker`

2. What I'm deploying is ASP.NET 5 beta 7 app, specifying:

   - URL: tcp://19.85.23.13:2376
   - Image: microsoft/aspnet

And leaving other parameters default. What I get is error:

> An error occured during publish. The command [docker -H
>   tcp://19.85.23.13:2376 build -t microsoft/aspnet -f
>   "C:\Users\adski\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\DockTest185\approot\src\DockTest1\Dockerfile"
>   "C:\Users\adski\AppData\Local\Temp\PublishTemp\DockTest185"] exited
>   with code [1]: Post
>   http://19.85.23.13:2376/v1.20/build?cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=approot%2Fsrc%2FDockTest1%2FDockerfile&memory=0&memswap=0&rm=1&t=microsoft%2Faspnet&ulimits=null:
>   dial tcp 19.85.23.13:2376: ConnectEx tcp: No connection could be made
>   because the target machine actively refused it..
>   * Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
>   * Is your docker daemon up and running?
>
> Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=529706 for
>   troubleshooting guide.

Well I'm not really a web-security expert. I've found this yet another manual: http://sheerun.net/2014/05/17/remote-access-to-docker-with-tls/ but can't really understand if it is what I need. After all, nobody in those "Visual Studio Publish to Docker" guides mentioned I need a certificate or something.

But obviously I need some credentials to access my server, otherwise, if it is on the web, anyone could dock something in it. And what are those cursed credentials? Any guides for dummies?

Edit 2: found something that looks like relevant: https://docs.docker.com/articles/https/

Er, is this really that complicated? But goddamit, none of those asp.net/docker tutorials mentioned that. Guides for dummies, pleeease?

Comment: Just curios, did you ever get this working?

Comment: Hi. I've found that I can't run Docker on the server I going to use due to 32-bit architecture (research was on VM), so I stopped further researching for now.